# jQuery Responsive Toggle Menu (ul on click return to parent) except on desktop

Tags: jquery, css

This menu works well on desktop but when I switch to mobile, I would like the menu to slideUp when the ul is clicked.  So far, the menu slides up when a user clicks on the top / main menu.  It is fine, but I'd like to have a better user experience by sliding / fading the sub menus.

Comment: Any solutions?  The desktop version should not be toggled.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/telosantos/7xtx6061/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you needed that other jQuery, but I just added the html into the doc and replaced your javascript with this:

```
$('#menu-button').on("click", function () {
    $('#cssmenu ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Taking advantage of jQuery's `slideToggle()` functionality.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/16cq72ms/3/

Comment: Thanks @pgruber I had tried the slideToggle function but I would like to do it on the parent and ul li menus. I would also like to slide the ul li and return to the main menu after clicking.

Comment: @telo78 So clicking on the dropdown would also slide the element up? Check out my updated fiddle and let me know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: damn, that was easy. i was using slideToggle on both selectors. thanks so much! i will update my code accordingly. :)

Comment: Glad it worked! I actually just cleaned it up so it should be even cleaner now.

Comment: i'll check the desktop version. it shouldn't toggle tho. but yeah works nice and simple.

Comment: Right on- in that case just role back to the old version: http://jsfiddle.net/16cq72ms/2/